# how to use a parameter for the available locale?

Tags: php, symfony, translation

In a symfony project I don't want to define the available locales for every route and use a parameter instead.

So following the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters) instead of witting:

```
team:
    resource: "Route/TeamRouting.yaml"
    prefix: /{_locale}/team/
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr
```

I used:

```
team:
    resource: "Route/TeamRouting.yaml"
    prefix: /{_locale}/team/
    requirements:
        _locale: '%supported_locales%'
```

and in my `service.yaml` file I defined:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    supported_locales: ['en', 'es', 'fr']
```

Unfortunately I get the following error :

> The container parameter "supported_locales", used in the route configuration value "%supported_locales%", must be a string or numeric, but it is of type array.

So how do I need to introduce my parameter to requirements ?

Comment: Did you try `supported_locales: 'en|es|fr'` ?

Comment: As a matter of fact no I didn't, but it worked thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a string for this parameter like this:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    supported_locales: 'en|es|fr'
```